# Can I un-concatenate multiple serialized files created with json/pickle?

Tags: python, json, pickle

I have many small python generated pickle dump files; I want to concatenate these files to one file and want the ability to un-concatenate  them when needed. Is it possible?

( using python 2.2 with pickle / Can consider json with python 2.6 if above is possible with json)

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use Python 2.2? Consider that it was released _twelve_ years ago...

Comment: Un-concatenate? Can we use another word? divide, disjoin, split....

Comment: No reason to stay on older version just that somebody has to do the change. It will need regression changes as dictionary order seems to have changed.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't generally possible with `json`, but I believe it should work OK with `pickle`.  you'd just use a `pickle.load` call for each "record" that was dumped.

Here, I've simulated your workflow with python2.7 and everything checks out OK:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('foo', 'wb') as p:
...     pickle.dump({1, 2, 3}, p)
... 
>>> with open('bar', 'wb') as p:
...     pickle.dump({4, 5, 6}, p)
... 
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'foo', 'bar'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> result = p.communicate(None)
>>> print result
('c__builtin__\nset\np0\n((lp1\nI1\naI2\naI3\natp2\nRp3\n.c__builtin__\nset\np0\n((lp1\nI4\naI5\naI6\natp2\nRp3\n.', None)
>>> import io
>>> stream = io.BytesIO(result[0])
>>> print pickle.load(stream)
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> print pickle.load(stream)
set([4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Thanks mgilson; will try it